# cut continuous variables to categorical variables in r (with separate values as groups)

Tags: r

I have a continuous variable ranging from 0 to 1000+. However, I want to convert them into groups with the lowest value 0 as a single group.

```
x <- cut(x, breaks = c(0,50,100,200,500,1000)),
                   labels = c("0","1-50","51-100","101-199","200-499",
                              "500-999",">1000")
```

Using cut function has not been able to achieve this purpose. Is there anything that I'm missing?

Answer (score 3):

You've got some issues in your call to `cut`

1. You've got a closing bracket after your `breaks` that should be there, prematurely ending the call.
2. You've too many labels (7) for the breaks (5).

This should work:

```
x <- cut(x, breaks = c(0,50,100,200,500,1000,max(x)),labels = c("0-50","51-100","101-199","200-499","500-999", "1000+"), include.lowest = TRUE)
```

Comment: Does your code translate into this [0-50], (51,100], (101,199]... ? What I intend to achieve is define "0" as the first group, then (0-50], (51,100], (101,199] etc. Don't know if I get myself accross now. Thank you anyway!